# In Gtk, how do I search a ListStore for the row containing a particular value?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#, gtktreeview

I have a `ListStore` modeling a list of `Tag`s. This list may change apart from the `ListStore`. What I'd like to do is listen to the `TagRemoved` event in my `TagList` class, and remove the `Tag` from the `ListStore` when the event is triggered. However, I can't seem to find a way to search a `ListStore` for the row containing a given `Tag`, so that I can remove it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426106/how-to-search-through-a-gtk-liststore-in-pygtk-and-remove-elements/58517988#58517988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `GtkListStore` implements the `GtkTreeModel` interface, which contains the tree traversal operations you want. As far as I know, there is no convenience API for searching a list/tree store, so you'll have to roll your own.

Since you're simply iterating over a `GtkListStore`, you can ignore all of the API dealing with child/parent relations, and simply use `gtk_tree_model_iter_first()` and `gtk_tree_model_iter_next()` to traverse the list.

Alternatively, if you already know the index of the removed tag in the store (e.g., from your `TagRemoved` event), you can turn that into a `GtkTreePath` and use `gtk_tree_model_get_iter()` to retrieve the row in question directly without searching.

Comment: `gtk_tree_model_iter_first` seems non-existend; I think you meant `gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first`.

Answer (score 1):

GtkListStore is internally implemented as a [linked list](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkListStore.html#id953074) so you should scan the model by yourself.