# How to search through a gtk.ListStore in pyGTK and remove elements?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have the following code (where store is a `gtk.ListStore` and titer is a `gtk.TreeIter`. The docs say that if there is no next row, `iter_next()` will return `None`, hence the break when that is found. It is supposed to search through the `ListStore` of `(int, str)` and remove the one item whose `int` component matches item_id.

```
    while True:
        if store.get_path(titer)[0] == item_id:
            store.remove(titer)
            break
        else:
            titer = store.iter_next(titer)
            if titer is None:
                break
```

However, if an element in the middle has previously been deleted, instead of `titer.iter_next()` pointing to the next valid element, it points to None. This means that if the element with the right `int` value is after the previously deleted item, it never gets found. Is there a correct way to search through a `gtk.ListStore` to remove items?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only mistake I notice is `store.get_path(titer)[0]`, which will just get the row number of the list model. It should be `store.get_value(titer, 0)`.

By the way, your code can be expressed in a simpler style using the (PyGTK-only) [TreeModelRow](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-pygtktreemodelrow.html):

```
for row in store:
    if row[0] == item_id:
        store.remove(row.iter)
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

sanity check: make sure there is data in your list store when trying to search it

```
    column_number = 0
    search_term = 'foo'
    iter_child = tree_model.get_iter_first()
    tree_path = None
    while iter_child:
        if (tree_model.get_value(iter_child, column_number) == search_term):
            tree_path = tree_model.get_path(iter_child)
        iter_child = tree_model.iter_next(iter_child)

    view.row_activated(tree_path, column_number)
    view.set_cursor(tree_path, column_number, True)
```