# How to get focus on a specific cell of Gtk.TreeView?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gtktreeview

I have a Gtk.TreeView instance and I also have the row and column index of the cell to be selected. How get to focus on the specific cell based those row and column index(int)?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426106/how-to-search-through-a-gtk-liststore-in-pygtk-and-remove-elements/58517988#58517988

Answer (score 2):

Based on the assumption that you actually mean to set the focus based on the `row` and `column` indexes you probably want to try using this function:

```
Treeview.row_activated(path, column)
```

[From the documentation:](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView.html#Gtk.TreeView.row_activated)

> **row_activated(path, column)**
>
> **Parameters:**
> *path* (Gtk.TreePath) – The Gtk.TreePath to be activated.
>
> *column* (Gtk.TreeViewColumn) – The Gtk.TreeViewColumn to be activated.
>
> Activates the cell determined by path and column.